# Read columns into separate lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a text file with more than 10 lines and 3 columns like:

```
Classification Type  A  B
Commercial Homes     12 15
Residential Homes    10 14
................     .. ..
```

I want to read each column separately like:

```
Classification = ['Commercial Homes', 'Residential Homes'.......]
A = [12,10,....]
B = [15,14,....]
```

I can use `split()` and read them into separate lists but classification names have more than one word and I have to capture full name in the list instead of first word. Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Comment: What are the columns delimited with? Tabs, spaces, commas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `zip()` to transpose the matrix represented by the csv reader object:

```
import csv

with open(fn) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    a, b, c = zip(*reader)

    print a
    ('Classification Type', 'Commercial Homes', 'Residential Homes')
    print b
    ('A', '12', '10')
    print c
    ('B', '15', '14')
    # trim the tuples as you wish, such as b=list(b[1:])...
```

Then, you may want a dict with the first value of that tuple:

```
data={}
for t in zip(*reader):
    data[t[0]]=t[1:]

print data    
# {'A': ('12', '10'), 'B': ('15', '14'), 'Classification Type': ('Commercial Homes', 'Residential Homes')}
```

Which then can be reduced to a single statement:

```
data={t[0]:t[1:] for t in zip(*reader)}
# {'A': ('12', '10'), 'B': ('15', '14'), 'Classification Type': ('Commercial Homes', 'Residential Homes')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
with open('./mydata', 'r') as raw_data:
    data = [line.strip().split() for line in raw_data.readlines()]
header = data.pop(0) ## Pop off header, removed from list
a = [record[1] for record in data]
b = [record[2] for record in data]
```

Obviously we are traversing the list twice, once for `a` and again for `b`.  For small data sets this won't pose any performance issue.

Alternatively we could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a = list()
b = list()
with open('./mydata', 'r') as raw_data:
    for line in raw_data:
        if line.startswith('Classification'):
            continue # skip the header line
        line = line.strip().split()
        a.append(line[1])
        b.append(line[2])
```

This is a bit more verbose.  But it does the work in a single pass through the data.

Comment: I used tab delimited to separate columns. It works then.

Comment: Ah! I missed that your leading comments on the data lines contained spaces. The Python .split() string method splits on any whitespace sequences by default.  You can supply arguments to split on other characters (but, in that case only single characters, to split on regular expressions you'd use the methods from the re module).  As others have said, to parse data from CSV (comma separated values) or similarly formatted sources use the csv module.  (I was focusing on the question of how to take the parsed data and separate specific columns out per your example.

Answer (score 0):

Use csv library to do the task

```
import csv

def main():
    with open(r'CSVReaderData.txt', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        col1, col2, col3 = zip(*reader)

    print 'Classification = ',list(col1)
    print 'A = ',list(col2)
    print 'B = ',list(col3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```