# How do I append values from a row in a CSV file into a list in python?

Tags: python, discrete-mathematics

If I have a csv file with only two rows containing an x and y coordinate, how would I go about taking row[0] and all its x points and appending them to a list?

In other words, lets say I have a list:

```
[[1,2], [3,5]]
```

Is there a way to take `1` and `3` and put them into a new list, and then `2` and `5` into another list?

Comment: So far I have only managed to get [[1,2], [3,5]], but my next step is wanting to adding the individual x and y. However, I realized that that is impossible if my list is in the form of list1 =[[1,2], [3,5]]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read columns into separate lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520820/read-columns-into-separate-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
points = [[1,2], [3,5]] #[[x,y],[x,y]]
x,y = zip(*points) #x = [1,3],y=[2,5]
```

this is an easy way to transpose any 2d array (take the rows and change them to columns)

if you had 3d points for example

```
points = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
x,y,z = zip(*points)
```

you can get your `points` from the csv

```
points = list(csv.reader(open("my_file.csv")))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what does zip(*points) do? I am wondering how I can take points from a row in excel and sum them up in python.

Comment: you said you had a list ... that list is points ... anyway theres one way to get your points out of a csv above ...